# Warning when opening a pdf file using either evince or atril

Tags: command-line, evince

I am using Ubuntu 16.10. When I try to open a pdf file using either evince or atril I see the following warning in the terminal:

```
(evince:4422): Gtk-WARNING **: Allocating size to EvSidebar 0x55756bb75f80q     
without calling gtk_widget_get_preferred_width/height(). 
How does the code know the size to allocate?
```

I can still open the pdf file. But this warning just looks annoying. I wonder if there is anything I can do to fix this bug. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just a warning for the developers to fix something in future versions, nothing for end-users to worry about. I run `atril` (in MATE 16.10) like this

```
atril /path/to/file.pdf > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

which sends all the warnings to oblivion and keeps my terminal clean.

Comment: neat! But is there way to set this command as the default command when opening a pdf file using atril. It is not pleasant to type so much when you just want to open a file

Comment: not as far as I know @Hongshan_Li but I use Ctrl+R a lot to reverse history search previous commands. You can shorten to `2>/dev/null`

Comment: @Hongshan_Li you could add an entry in your ``.mailcap`` to specify which program to open PDF file, use ``application/pdf;`` followed by the command provided by @Zanna.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following function in the global `bashrc`:

NOTE: the missing 'e' is on purpose -- you must rename the command or else you get infinite recursion.

```
evinc()
{
    evince $1 > /dev/null 2>&1 & 
}
```

Comment: Note that using absolute path inside the function would also avoid recursion :)

Comment: Whilst this may work, it disables all output and the warning does still actually exist, it is just unseen.